# Using Keycloack: how to define different sets of roles for a single user working for two companies?

Tags: keycloak

I have an application where right now a user could work in different context : in the same client application he could switch his context and work either for a company1 as "Administrator" or if he switch to the second context , he could work as "Editor" for the company2…
This was done by using a custom homemade authorization module, but we are trying to use openid-connect now so we are trying to find some solutions with KeyCloack.
Is it possible to assure the same kind of thing in Keycloack ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. BUT it's not something that anyone who doesn't know the internal of your custom implementation could give you a solution.

Authorization services provided by Keycloak is quite flexible and of course complex. I suggest you to take a look at the following link and see which of of authorization solution can answer your requirements and would also be possible to adopt your system to use it (e.g. RBAC, ABAC, CBAC, etc.).

As an example, one solution could be to consider each company a resource and then each user of the application, can have different roles/permissions on each resource. So in Keycloak you define who has what roles on which resources (companies) and then in your app, you check those to see if user is authorized or not. But I'm pretty sure when you get a better overview of the Authorization Services in Keycloak, you would come up with a much better idea.

- [Keycloak Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/)